# Sort an Array List based on user input?

Tags: arrays, sorting, arraylist

So I have an Array List which contains a list of favorite colors. For example, the Array reads as- Red, Blue, Green. But now I want the user to be able to "rank" their favorite colors because the current list is not their personal ranking. So how would I move one element of the array list down to another spot. I want the program to say "The first item on the list is red, where would you rank it?" and then they can say they want it in the 3rd spot. And then so on until they rank all of them. The problem is I'm new to Array Lists and dont know how to do this. Would I be using Collections.sort(array list); ? How would I even call upon the elements of the array in order to ask them? Is is something like (using pseudo code here) line 1/element 1 of array list?

Code so far(the last part doesnt really work properly, but you'll see where I'm trying to go)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <String> favoriteColors = new ArrayList <String>();
        boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat) {

            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file which contains your favorite colors ");
            String fileName = input.nextLine().trim();

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

                String line;
                System.out.println("Here are your favorite colors according to the file:");  
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                   System.out.println(line);   
                   favoriteColors.add((line));
                 }                                                

                 System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
                 if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                     System.out.println("Enter : ");
                     favoriteColors.add(input.next());
                 } else {
                     break;
                 }
                 for (int i = 0; i < favoriteColors.size(); i++) {
                     System.out.println(favoriteColors);
                 }

                     System.out.println("Remove a color?");

                     if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                         System.out.println("Which color would you like to remove");
                            String removeColor = input.nextLine();
                            int index = favoriteColor.indexOf(removeColor);
                            favoriteColor.remove(index);
                            System.out.println(favoriteColor);
                     }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what you have code for what you have done? At least post code for the initializing the Array List. Are you using a python list, numpy array, or an array?

Comment: @imp9 just added my code

Answer (score 0):

"I want the program to say 'The first item on the list is red, where would you rank it?' and then they can say they want it in the 3rd spot. And then so on until they rank all of them."
To do this, you'll want to create a new list, that's the same length as the original list, but each value in it is some empty color, and then you will go through the original list, asking them where they would rank each color, and inserting the color into the position they would rank it at. You can get values from array lists using ".get(index)". An example:
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        a.get(5)

This would technically throw an error, because a doesn't have an element at index 5, but that's besides the point for this example.

Comment: thank you, follow up-is there an easy way to make the new list the same length as the original one? Because its not a set amount- they can add a color or subtract one

Comment: There's an easy way to find out how long the list currently is. It's called ".size()". Here's the documentation for ArrayList, you can see all the functions defined for it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html